# HTTPPost returns empty values in my complex model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Complex model in a View, which is editable.  In my View, when I click save, the model returned is null or empty, except for the "nri_id" value.  I've looked at a bunch of the other posts and tried them all but can't seem to get mine to work.  I feel like i'm just missing something simple.....

```
public partial class nri
{
    public nri()
    {
        tasks = new HashSet<task>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int nri_id { get; set; }
    public int ref_number { get; set; }
    public int state_id { get; set; }

    [UIHint("_taskList")]
    public virtual ICollection<task> tasks { get; set; }
}
```

and a view:

```
@model NSCEngineering.Models.nri

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>nri</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.nri_id)
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.state_id)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.state_id)
            </dd>
             <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ref_number)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ref_number)
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <h4>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.tasks)</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tasks)
    </div>
</div>
}
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
```

and my controller:

```
    // GET: nris/Details/5
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id = 0)
    {
        nri n = await _nriRepository.GetNRIByID(id);       
        return View(n);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Details(nri nriModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _nriRepository.UpdateNRI(nriModel);
                _nriRepository.SaveAll();
                return View(nriModel);
            }
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(nriModel);
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Changed all the `@Html.DisplayFor` to @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.xxxx, new { @readonly = "readonly" })`, and that did the trick.

My Task EditorTemplate is below.  I have a Hieriachal table,' category', which groups and displays the tasks accordingly.  I'm assuming i'll also need a `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.nri_id)` somewhere in there too...:

```
@model IEnumerable<NSCEngineering.Models.task>

<div class="form-group">
    @{var categories = ViewData["AllCategories"] as List<NSCEngineering.Models.category>;}  

    @for (int i=0; i < (categories.Where(x=>x.parent_category_id ==null)).Count(); i++)
    {
    <dl>
        <dt>@Html.DisplayFor(x => categories[i].category_name)</dt>
        @{IEnumerable<NSCEngineering.Models.task> CategoryTasks = Model.Where(z => z.category_id == categories[i].category_id);}
        @foreach (var task in CategoryTasks) {     
        <dd>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => task, "_task")
            </dd>
        }
        @*}*@
        @for (int j = 0; j < categories[i].Subcategories.Count(); j++ )
        {
            <dd>
                <dl>
                    <dt>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => categories[i].Subcategories[j].category_name)
                    </dt>
                    @{IEnumerable<NSCEngineering.Models.task> subTasks = Model.Where(task => task.category_id == categories[i].Subcategories[j].category_id); }
                    @foreach (var subtask in subTasks)
                    {
                        <dd>
                            @Html.EditorFor(x => subtask, "_task")
                        </dd>
                    }
                </dl>
            </dd>
        }
    </dl>
}
```

and my Task Template:

```
@model NSCEngineering.Models.task

<tr>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.task_id)
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.task_name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.task_desc)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.task_state_id, new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["TaskStates"], "task_state_id", "state"))
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.user_completed)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.completion_date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor()` does not create a control that posts back a value. You need to use `TextBoxFor()` or `HiddenFor()` for properties that you want to post back (as you have done for the `nri_id` property)

Comment: what is "task"?  Or use EditorFor instead of DisplayFor

Comment: @StephenMuecke !! that solves one problem.  Is adding `new { @readonly = "readonly" }` a safe way to make it read-only?

Comment: @Eru please see my Edit for the Task EditorFor. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can do that, or add a hidden input for the property with `@HiddenFor()`, but it not good practice to include a lot of hidden inputs - if your not editing them, its generally better performance to get the object from the database and update the properties you want rather than posting a whole lot of extra data across the wire

Comment: Also your `EditorTemplate` is all wrong. If you have a look at the html generated you will probably see that the indexers are not consecutive and may not even start at zero, so it wont post back

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was under the impression that since it was an IEnumerable that Razor would take care of the indexing... I changed all the foreach loops to for loops, but still am getting no tasks returned.

Comment: Yes, but if you have `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.tasks)` then the `Task.cshtml` template should be `@model Task`, not `@model IEnumerable<Task>` (but then you also seem to have another template with `@model Task` so not really sure what your actually trying to do here. (and again, many of the helpers in the templates are not rendering controls that will post back a value)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was using the `@model IEnumerable<Task>` to group and display the tasks hierarhally by category.

Comment: AS you have discovered that wont work. If you include the model for `Task` in your question, I'll have a look a bit later today. Note this is a classic case for using a view model to represent what you want to display/edit